# Suppose we flip 100 fair independent coins. What is the probability that at least three of them are heads?

Tags: probability

Suppose we flip 100 fair independent coins. What is the probability that at least
three of them are heads?

Sample space would be $\{100 \text{ coins with possibility } H, T\}^{100} = 2^5$

Now to find the times it would be at least three heads

So I'm guessing we flip 100 coins

Could someone help me please

Comment: Hint: Prob(At least 3) = 1 - Prob(None) - Prob(exactly 1) - Prob(exactly 2). Now use the binomial distribution.

Comment: You say "Sample space would be $\{\text{100 coins with possibility H,T}\}^{100}=2^5$".  There are many things wrong with that.  If you insist on specifying some sample space (*and insist on the sample space being equiprobable and our desired event being a subset of that sample space*), then a good way of describing it would be $\{H,T\}^{100}$ which would be *of cardinality* $2^{100}$.  The sample space is a set.  The sample space is not *equal* to $2^{100}$, it merely has $2^{100}$ as its "*size*."  Note further, $2^5$ is nowhere near $2^{100}$ in size, off by several orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of "at least three of the 100 coins are heads" is 1 **minus** the probability that there are 0, 1, of 2 heads.  If there are 0 heads then all 100 must be tails.  The probability of that is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}$.  If there is 1 head, there are 99 tails.  The probability of that is $\frac{100!}{99! 1!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}= 100\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}$.  If there are 2 heads, there are 98 tails.  The probability of that is $\frac{100}{98!2!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}= 4950\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}$.  The sum of those is $(1+ 100+ 4950)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}= 5051\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}$.

The probability of "at least thee of the 100 coins are heads" is $1- 5051\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}$.